Apache with Perl FastCGI - Internal Server Error
I can't get Apache and FastCGI for Perl running properly on Debian 12.
What I have done so far:
apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid
a2enmod fcgid

My Vhost file looks like this:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin it@example.org
    ServerName test.example.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vzt

    SetEnv SIMPLESAMLPHP_CONFIG_DIR /var/www/vzt/required/sso

    Alias /simplesaml /var/www/vzt/vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/public

    <Directory /var/www/vzt>
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler fcgid-script .cgi
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vzt_access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.org/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.org/privkey.pem
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

I have a simple Perl test script which has the appropriate permissions and the appropriate owner (-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data):
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";
print "Hello, World! This is a FastCGI test script.\n";

After restarting Apache and calling the script via HTTP through the browser I get Internal Server Error - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. and /var/log/apache2/error.log says:
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello, World! This is a FastCGI test script.
2024-07-22 22:50:04 [warn] [pid 158161] fcgid_proc_unix.c(627): (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 5.1.2.3:32152] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
2024-07-22 22:50:04 [error] [pid 158161] util_script.c(501): [client 5.1.2.3:32152] End of script output before headers: test_plain.cgi

Any advice on how to get this running would be highly appreciated. Thanks.
EDIT: /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.load (+ *.conf) is loaded in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf through IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load (+ *.conf).
EDIT: The Perl and Apache FastCGI modules are installed, libcgi-fast-perl, libcgi-pm-perl, libfcgi-perl and libapache2-mod-fcgid.
